# Why it takes such a long time for my server to receive the data?

Tags: android, sockets

I am writing code to transfer data from the android client on my phone to the server on my PC. I think when I call the function to send data on my client it should send the data to the client and the client would show it. However, it takes a long time for the message(2min) to show on my PC. Now it even shows nothing on the server. Sometimes it does not show any message. I wonder why this happens.
Here is my code of sending data on my client:

```
String str="abc";
btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                
            mThreadPool.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                        PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(outputStream);

                        InputStream is=socket.getInputStream();
                        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                        pw.write(str);                          
                        pw.flush();
                        String reply=null;
                        while(!((reply=br.readLine())==null)){
                            System.out.println("Receive the data of the server："+reply);
                        }
                   
                        br.close();
                        is.close();
                        pw.close();
                        outputStream.close();
                        socket.close();


                    } catch (IOException e) {
                         Log.d("send",Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                    }
                    catch(NullPointerException e)
                    {
                        Log.d("send",Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                    }

                }
            });
```

Here is the code of receiving data in the server:

```
try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket=new ServerSocket(9102);
            Socket socket=serverSocket.accept();
            InputStream is=socket.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            String info=null;
            while(!((info=br.readLine())==null)){
                System.out.println("I am the server："+info);
            }
            OutputStream os=socket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(os);
            String reply="welcome";
            pw.write(reply);
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();

            br.close();
            is.close();
            socket.close();
            serverSocket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


}
```

And here is the logcat:
[The logcat of the client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEBCw.jpg)

Comment: `I think when I call my press the send button on my client it should send the data to the client and the client would show it.` That makes no sense. I think it should send the data to the server and the server should show it.

Comment: Have you tried without the `System.out.println()` inside the `while` loop on both ends?

Comment: I have tried without the System.out.println() inside the while loop, and nothing be output.@MarkusKauppinen

Comment: When I press the send button, the function to send data is called. Sorry for my error in the text.@blackapps

Comment: Then correct your post to begin with.

Comment: `pw.write(str);` We cannot see what you send. Please edit your code to show.

Comment: Now the server shows nothing and after a long time, it ends. I have editted the code and add the description. Please help me with it.@blackapps

Comment: If the receiver tries to read a line then the sender should have send one. It looks as you only try to read lines and never send one. I hope you know what would be a line.